# Where is sqlite database in android tablet?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am developing a application in which, insert some values in local sqlite database.
Its working fine on local Emulator and Tablet as well as. After inserting values, I want to get sqlite database. I am able to get database from Emulator but unfortunatally unable to get sqlite database from Android Tablet. 
Please suggest what is procedure to get database from real device(Tablet).

Thanks.

Comment: are you asking about,you not able to find the database from your SDcard??

Comment: No you cant access Android Real Device db, its kind of security hack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank for all of you

Finally i got a proper solution. We can't get db from any (Samsung) tablet, but we can copy its data and can pull to our PC.

```
public void copyDataBase() {
        Log.i("info", "in copy data base at finally");
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "/data/" + context.getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/DB_29Apr.sqlite";
                String backupDBPath = "DB_29Apr.sqlite";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB)
                            .getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB)
                            .getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("info", "in copy of bata base 10 ");

        }
    }
```

From above function you can copy the db on external space of tablet.

Go to DDMS and find the defined database with given name in db at storage place in tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Create one folder named database manually in your tablet sdcard.
Then run your application and then open the database folder to get .db file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select this from **FileExplorer**  `mnt---> sdcard---> your DB_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

FYI In Tablet device for security purpose it does not allow to find you .db file.
If you are using emulator then you have permission to access location[directory] of database.

This is final answer.

Thank you

Comment: It does not allow to write .db file in tablet, But surely we can read it.

Comment: yes that can possible,here the guy face the problem of access .db file from out side because if he was able to run in emulator then same thing he can able to read in tablet device.so my answer was to access file from outside.

Comment: Would you please give me way to get file from tablet?

Comment: can you send me location of db file,i mean path of you db file.

Comment: I am unable to get location in devices.
I am writing it on following path
DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + mycontext.getPackageName() + "/databases/";

Answer (score 1):

reason you can not able because it would created in following location like

```
/data/data/<your root package name in android manifest file>/databases/< you database name>
```

which can only accessed by your application so simply copy you file from above location to sd card location Programmatically use below function might be help for copy stream

```
public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    final int buffer_size = 1024;
    try {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer_size];
        for (;;) {
            int count = is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
            if (count == -1)
                break;
            os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```